# How do I edit the VIM Omni Completion so that all CSS properties do not end in a colon?

Tags: css, plugins, vim, omnicomplete

I have been exploring some way in VIM to automatically append closing characters to a line of code. In my case it is CSS. I came across this tip http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters and tweaked the code it tells me to add to my `.vimrc` like so

```
inoremap {      {}<Left>
inoremap {<CR>  {<CR>}<Esc>O
inoremap {{     {
inoremap {}     {}
```

so when I write

```
body
```

and then press { and ENTER in rapid succession what results is

```
body {

}
```

Note that the cursor will be indented and on the 2nd line so I will be ready to write code in that block.

Also I should mention that I also added the following to my `.vimrc`

```
inoremap ::     :;<Left>
```

so that when I type : and : in rapid succession I will get `:;` with the cursor located in between the `:` and `;`. This exactly where I want to be so I can start writing code right away.

I got that working fine but I quickly realized that the auto complete plug in that I installed (AutoComplPop VIM plug-in http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) conflicts with the above `.vimrc` tweak.

So for example, if I start to write `color` I get the drop auto completion drop down menu of all options. The problem is that the option for `color` is actually `color:`.

[image]

You see it has a colon already added to it so when I select it, the colon is already there and then I have to manually add the closing `;` character. This basically defeats the whole purpose of adding the auto appending closing character code to my `.vimrc` since in this case, it does not auto append the closing semicolon.

**So how do I make a custom edit to VIM's Omni Completion so that all CSS properties do not end in a colon?**

CSS auto completion options for VIM and came across AutoComplPop here http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on a UNIX-like system…

1. Copy

   ```
   /usr/share/vim/vim7x/autoload/csscomplete.vim
   ```

   to

   ```
   ~/.vim/autoload/csscomplete.vim
   ```
2. Find the loop that generates the list of properties, for me it's at line 92.
3. Remove the colon from the second parameter of the two `add()`.

   These lines:

   ```
   call add(res, m . ':')
   call add(res2, m . ':')
   ```

   become:

   ```
   call add(res, m)
   call add(res2, m)
   ```
4. Save the file.

---

Also there are [many plugins](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=auto%20closing&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search) for "auto closing" pairs of characters. I use [DelimitMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2754).

And the issue is not related to ACP at all.

Comment: Thanks that worked but tell me, do you use DelimitMate with Omni Completion (or AutoComplPop)? Does DelimitMate take into consideration the fact that default OmniCompletion adds the `:` after CSS properties?

Comment: Completion and autopairing don't always work well together. Doing HTML with both sucks. I have a love/hate relationship with autocompletion and I turn it off quite often. Using the default mechanisms only when I need.

Comment: I just tried DelimitMate and it seems to work but there is an issue. If I do `body {` it will automatically add a `}` right after but if I press Enter to go to the next line no indentation happens and the `}` is to the right of my cursor. What I would like to have happen is when I press Enter my cursor goes to the line below, gets indented, the `}` drops to the line below my cursor and is pinned to the left edge. Do you know is this is possible with DelimitMate?

Comment: Yes, add `let delimitMate_expand_cr=1` to your `~/.vimrc` and don't forget a) to read the documentation, `:h delimitmate` and b) to test the dozen or so alternatives. Other plugins may better fit your needs.